# Why I get error 400 bad request when sending variables in the URL django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm using django 2.1 this is my urlpatterns:

`from referrals import views as referrals_views
urlpatterns = [
path('referrals_details/<int:patient_id>', referrals_views.referrals_details,
         name='referrals_details'),]`

I use a varible to indicate the id of the user I want to get. I´ve noticed that when sending a request, in my console I get:

> "GET /referral/referrals_details/1 HTTP/1.1" 200 180
>   code 400, message Bad request syntax ('----------------------------563121910873865134633264')
>   ["----------------------------563121910873865134633264" 400 -

This issue is only when I use variables in the URL, I get my responses right though. Doing a quick search the main reason to this problem is requesting as Https, something that I'm not doing, I'm using Postman to send the requests.

Comment: Can you please post the *full* traceback? It is not said that this has much to do withtue `urls.py`. Furthermore Django-3.9 does, to the best of my knowledge, not yet exists.

Comment: I have just update the full message in my console, I'm not getting an error in the browser